# Why it's called "hunky dory"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I saw a phrase

> If everything is ***hunky dory***, you'll hear a ...

Miss Google says it means something is fine, but I want to know the story behind it?

Comment: Exact dupe: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11717/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-hunky-dory

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's a duplicate on ELU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following explanation comes from the source below, where more information can be found.

*"There's no agreed derivation of the expression 'hunky-dory'. It is American and the earliest example of it in print that I have found is from a collection of US songs, George Christy's Essence of Old Kentucky, 1862:

Hunkey Dorey

As sung by Christy's Minstrels.
Air - "Limerick Races"
One of the boys am I,
That always am in clover;
With spirits light and high,
'Tis well I'm known all over.
I am always to be found,
A singing in my glory;
With your smiling faces round,
'Tis then I'm hunkey dorey.

The Christy Minstrels were a 'blackface' minstrel group formed by Edwin Pearce Christy, George Christy's father. Both men were born in the USA, but Christy is an Irish surname and the tone of the above lyrics, along with the Limerick-based tune, all point to an Irish association with the phrase.*

See more at:

https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/hunky-dory.html

Comment: Sometimes something just happen, no reason needed, sounds like a happy ending for me. No story is a long story.